# copy nodes based on key values in previous node

Tags: xslt, key, xslt-1.0

I have the following input XML and want to copy the "Delivery" `Stop` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LeanXML>
    <ShipperLoadPlan>
        <LoadNumber>129516728</LoadNumber>
        <Stops>
            <Stop>
                <StopNumber>1</StopNumber>
                <StopType>Pickup</StopType>
                <Distance UOM="mi">0</Distance>
                <CalcDueDate TimeZone="EDT" TimeZoneDesc="America/New_York">09/27/2021
                    00:00</CalcDueDate>
                <ReferenceNums/>
                <OrderNums>
                    <OrderNum ShipperRef="6000002014_30SAP" ShipmentLegID="291"
                        ShipmentLegSeq="1" ScheduleIntgKey="1">6000002014</OrderNum>
                    <OrderNum ShipperRef="6000002014_10SAP" ShipmentLegID="2916"
                        ShipmentLegSeq="1" ScheduleIntgKey="1">6000002014</OrderNum>
                </OrderNums>
            </Stop>
            <Stop>
                <StopNumber>2</StopNumber>
                <StopType>Delivery</StopType>
                <Distance UOM="mi">0</Distance>
                <CalcDueDate TimeZone="CDT" TimeZoneDesc="America/Chicago">10/01/2021
                    00:00</CalcDueDate>
                <ReferenceNums/>
                <OrderNums>
                    <OrderNum ShipperRef="R6000002014_10SAP" ShipmentLegID="291608671"
                        ShipmentLegSeq="1" ScheduleIntgKey="1">6000002014</OrderNum>
                </OrderNums>
            </Stop>
            <Stop>
                <StopNumber>3</StopNumber>
                <StopType>Delivery</StopType>
                <Distance UOM="mi">473</Distance>
                <CalcDueDate TimeZone="CDT" TimeZoneDesc="America/Chicago">10/03/2021
                    00:00</CalcDueDate>
                <ReferenceNums/>
                <OrderNums>
                    <OrderNum ShipperRef="R6000002014_30SAP" ShipmentLegID="291634632"
                        ShipmentLegSeq="1" ScheduleIntgKey="1">6000002014</OrderNum>
                </OrderNums>
            </Stop>
        </Stops>
        <DivertedOrders/>
        <CompanyDefined/>
    </ShipperLoadPlan>
    
</LeanXML>
```

I came up with this XSLT using a Key I put on the `StopType` = Pickup:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs xd"
    version="1.0">
    
    
    <xsl:key name="keyOrderLineNum" match="Stop[StopType='Pickup']/OrderNums" 
        use="concat(OrderNum/@ShipperRef,'|',../../CalcDueDate,'|',../../StopNumber)"/>
  
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
         <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    
    <xsl:template match="Stop[StopType='Pickup']">
        
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
            <CopiedStop>
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:value-of select="parent::Stops/Stop[StopType='Delivery']"/>
                </xsl:copy>
               
            </CopiedStop>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I am expecting this target XML, my bit question mark is how do I properly use my key to copy the Delivery Stop elements?
Expected Target:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<LeanXML>
    <ShipperLoadPlan>
        <LoadNumber>129516728</LoadNumber>
        <Stops>
            <Stop>
                <StopNumber>1</StopNumber>
                <StopType>Pickup</StopType>
                <Distance UOM="mi">0</Distance>
                <CalcDueDate TimeZone="EDT" TimeZoneDesc="America/New_York">09/27/2021
                    00:00</CalcDueDate>
                <ReferenceNums/>
                <OrderNums>
                    <OrderNum ShipperRef="6000002014_30SAP" ShipmentLegID="291"
                        ShipmentLegSeq="1" ScheduleIntgKey="1">6000002014</OrderNum>
                    <OrderNum ShipperRef="6000002014_10SAP" ShipmentLegID="2916"
                        ShipmentLegSeq="1" ScheduleIntgKey="1">6000002014</OrderNum>
                </OrderNums>
                <CopiedStop>
                    <Stop>
                        <StopNumber>2</StopNumber>
                        <StopType>Delivery</StopType>
                        <Distance UOM="mi">0</Distance>
                        <CalcDueDate TimeZone="CDT" TimeZoneDesc="America/Chicago">10/01/2021
                            00:00</CalcDueDate>
                        <ReferenceNums/>
                        <OrderNums>
                            <OrderNum ShipperRef="R6000002014_10SAP" ShipmentLegID="291608671"
                                ShipmentLegSeq="1" ScheduleIntgKey="1">6000002014</OrderNum>
                        </OrderNums>
                    </Stop>
                    <Stop>
                        <StopNumber>3</StopNumber>
                        <StopType>Delivery</StopType>
                        <Distance UOM="mi">473</Distance>
                        <CalcDueDate TimeZone="CDT" TimeZoneDesc="America/Chicago">10/03/2021
                            00:00</CalcDueDate>
                        <ReferenceNums/>
                        <OrderNums>
                            <OrderNum ShipperRef="R6000002014_30SAP" ShipmentLegID="291634632"
                                ShipmentLegSeq="1" ScheduleIntgKey="1">6000002014</OrderNum>
                        </OrderNums>
                    </Stop>
                </CopiedStop>
            </Stop>
            <Stop>
                <StopNumber>2</StopNumber>
                <StopType>Delivery</StopType>
                <Distance UOM="mi">0</Distance>
                <CalcDueDate TimeZone="CDT" TimeZoneDesc="America/Chicago">10/01/2021
                    00:00</CalcDueDate>
                <ReferenceNums/>
                <OrderNums>
                    <OrderNum ShipperRef="R6000002014_10SAP" ShipmentLegID="291608671"
                        ShipmentLegSeq="1" ScheduleIntgKey="1">6000002014</OrderNum>
                </OrderNums>
            </Stop>
            <Stop>
                <StopNumber>3</StopNumber>
                <StopType>Delivery</StopType>
                <Distance UOM="mi">473</Distance>
                <CalcDueDate TimeZone="CDT" TimeZoneDesc="America/Chicago">10/03/2021
                    00:00</CalcDueDate>
                <ReferenceNums/>
                <OrderNums>
                    <OrderNum ShipperRef="R6000002014_30SAP" ShipmentLegID="291634632"
                        ShipmentLegSeq="1" ScheduleIntgKey="1">6000002014</OrderNum>
                </OrderNums>
            </Stop>
        </Stops>
        <DivertedOrders/>
        <CompanyDefined/>
    </ShipperLoadPlan>
    
</LeanXML>
```

Can anyone help me please achieve this? I appreciate any tips on this.

Comment: Can you explain the required logic in words? What exactly ties the "Delivery" Stops to the "Pickup" Stop? Surely its cannot be the StopNumber which is different for every stop? Likewise in your example, the ShipperRef and CalcDueDate are different, so cannot be used as the key values.

Comment: Hello Michael, thank you for your help. What ties "Pickup" and "Delivery" stops together is the "ShipperRef" - I just corrected them, the always consist of a PO number and then the line number and the "SAP" suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAICT, you want to do something like:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="deiveryStops" match="Stop[StopType='Delivery']" use="OrderNums/OrderNum" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
      
<xsl:template match="Stop[StopType='Pickup']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
        <CopiedStop>
            <xsl:copy-of select="key('deiveryStops', OrderNums/OrderNum)"/>
        </CopiedStop>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This ties the "Delivery" Stops to the "Pickup" Stop based on matching `OrderNum` alone.

Comment: Hello Michael, thank you for your help. This looks so easy, I was thinking way to complicated when setting up my key and the rest. Matching the "OrderNum" elements looks good, no need to go into the CalcDueDate or the stop number. I still have to test it out. I will get back to you.

Comment: Hello Michael, thank you again, I just accepted your answer after testing it. I was thinking too complicated. Will keep that as an example in my cheat sheet.